# Prove by induction that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(1 + \sqrt{3})^n + (1 - \sqrt{3})^n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(1 + \sqrt{3})^n + (1 - \sqrt{3})^n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  It should making typing your questions, answers, and comments easier in future.  As for your question, what have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If you know the binomial theorem, you can prove this very easily without induction. If you must prove it by induction, you may find it easier to prove a stronger statement:

> Let $\alpha=1+\sqrt3$ and $\beta=1-\sqrt3$. Then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ both $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and $\sqrt3(\alpha^n-\beta^n)$ are integers.

The following calculation will be useful for the induction step:

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}&=\alpha^n+\sqrt3\alpha^n+\beta^n-\sqrt3\beta^n\\
&=(\alpha^n+\beta^n)+\sqrt3(\alpha^n-\beta^n)\\
\end{align*}$$

You will want a similar one involving $\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}$.

(This is an example of a not uncommon phenomenon: sometimes an induction argument requires a stronger hypothesis than the obvious one and works only after you realize that you can prove a stronger statement.)

Answer (score 2):

A start: For convenience let our numbers be $a$ and $b$. For the induction step,  use the identity
$$a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}=(a^k+b^k)(a+b)-ab(a^{k-1}+b^{k-1}).$$
Technically speaking, you will be using *strong induction*.

Answer (score 2):

$$ A^{n+1} + B^{n+1} = (A+B)(A^n + B^n)-AB(A^{n-1} + B^{n-1}) $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be your expression. Show that $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence of the form $a_{n+2} = A a_{n+1} +B a_n$ and that $a_0,a_1$ are integers. Then prove your claim by induction.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Use the binomial theorem.